# How does one identify the linux distro in use?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

What I normally do to at least get some idea of what branch we're talking about, I try to run `apt-get`, `pacman`, `yum` and all other common package managers that I can remember off the top of my head, but I'm sure there's a better way, so: Is there a simple way of, by using shell only, identifying which linux distribution you just logged in to?

Comment: [How can I get distribution name and version number in a simple shell script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6345)

Comment: Answers involving the kernel version (e.g. `uname -a` and `cat /proc/version` aren't correct, since the concept of a "distribution" is foreign to the Linux kernel.   Note that the Linux system may not be from any distro at all, that is, it could be a custom-built kernel and rootfs.

Comment: @DavidPostill It would be great if `/etc/lsb-release` was more de facto - it was only present on 1 of the 4 I tried below.

Comment: lsb-release is usually *optional*

Comment: Cat /etc/*release*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the distro.

Debian and relatives use

```
     lsb_release -a
     cat /etc/lsb-release
```

either one should be fine. But, despite this being related to LSB (Linux Standard Base), not all distros have it. If you get no reply from the above commands, you should try

```
      ls /etc/*release
```

and then look inside whichever file you found. You must be careful to this: while RedHat does have /etc/redhat-release, others, like Arch Linux, have an **empty** /etc/arch-release file, and the one that does contain the info you are looking for is */etc/os-release*.

So, YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be foolproof, but `/proc/version` should at least give you a ballpark:

Redhat derivative:

```
# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.18-92cp (builder@Lnx30BccCmp5) (gcc version 4.1.1 20061011 (Red Hat 4.1.1-30)) #1 SMP Wed Apr 8 17:12:19 IDT 2015
```

Ubuntu:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-24-generic (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014
```

Debian:

```
$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1
```

Centos:

```
# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.18-400.el5xen (mockbuild@builder17.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)) #1 SMP Thu Dec 4 13:29:23 EST 2014
```

Comment: As advertised, not foolproof, but a lot easier than my method of checking the package manager. `/proc/version` on Mint Ubuntu, but it's close enough.

Answer (score 1):

On modern Fedora and Debian (and Arch, CentOS, CoreOS, Mageia, openSUSE, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server, Ubuntu, and others) the easiest way is to look at `/etc/os-release` or run `hostnamectl status`.

In a script, you could simply do

```
#!/bin/sh
source /etc/os-release
echo $PRETTY_NAME
```

For example:

```
$ source /etc/os-release
$ echo $PRETTY_NAME
Fedora 25 (Workstation Edition)
```

...

```
$ source /etc/os-release 
$ echo $PRETTY_NAME
Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
```

Of course, if you need to identify old versions or non-systemd distros as well, you could simply start with this approach if `/etc/os-release` exists, and if it doesn't, fall back to looking for `lsb_release`, `/etc/redhat-release`, trying to figure it out from `/proc/version`, or some other heuristic.

See [Detecting Linux distribution name and version](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/linux/872/detecting-linux-distribution-name-and-version/6236/detect-what-systemd-based-distribution-you-are-using#t=201612131700179564694) on Stack Overflow Documentation for more.

Answer (score 1):

I use **[screenFetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch)** - The Bash Screenshot Information Tool:

[image: screenfetch]

Answer (score 0):

```
uname -a
```

Should do the trick. It will display system information on the distro you're logged in.

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

Should also display the distro name and version.

Comment: Nope, it only shows hostname, kernel and platform, not distro.

Comment: Okay. I updated my answer. That should display the distro name and version. Or at least it did on mine on Linux Mint.