# How to tell whether it is Fedora or Debian using a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, unix, fedora

I am learning the basics of scripting and trying to write a script to decide what flavour of Linux the script is run on. I have come up with a simple version as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
     which yum >/dev/null && { echo Fedora flavour; exit 0; }
     which zypper >/dev/null && { echo Suse of sorts; exit 0; }
     which apt-get >/dev/null && { echo Debian based;  }
```

Is there a more graceful way to decide what Linux flavour I am running on?
Is there a way to include Unix - or make it generic for Xnix of any sort?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: this is not a duplicate of [How does one identify the linux distro in use?](https://superuser.com/questions/929741/how-does-one-identify-the-linux-distro-in-use) for the following reasons:
For Ubuntu, `cat /etc/lsb-release` works like a charm, for RedHat, it doesn't. 
`ls /etc/*release` does, but it lists three folders. `cat /proc/version` looks promising but needs some regex magic.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/929741/how-does-one-identify-the-linux-distro-in-use

Comment: @golimar, thanks. Almost, but not quite what I am looking for. For Ubuntu, cat /etc/lsb-release works like a charm, for RedHat, it doesn't. ls /etc/*release does, but it lists three folders, so I'd need more digging. cat /proc/version looks promising but needs some regex magic. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: `/etc/lsb-release` will work on Red Hat family distributions if you install the LSB packages — but we don't by default.

Comment: I think this *is* a duplicate — the fact that the answer there that you tried isn't comprehensive doesn't make it less so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one identify the linux distro in use?](http://superuser.com/questions/929741/how-does-one-identify-the-linux-distro-in-use)

Answer (score 4):

On modern Fedora and Debian (and Arch, CentOS, CoreOS, Mageia, openSUSE, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server, Ubuntu, and others) the easiest way is to look at `/etc/os-release` or run `hostnamectl status`.

In a script, you could simply do

```
#!/bin/sh
source /etc/os-release
echo $PRETTY_NAME
```

Of course, if you need to identify old versions or non-systemd distros as well, you could simply start with the above but if `/etc/os-release` does not exist jump to further heuristics.

See [Detecting Linux distribution name and version](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/linux/872/detecting-linux-distribution-name-and-version/6236/detect-what-systemd-based-distribution-you-are-using#t=201612131700179564694) on Stack Overflow Documentation for more.

Comment: RedHat, Centos and SUSE are not Debian based.

Comment: @andrej Of course they aren't. But the above will work on all of them, assuming new enough versions.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with:

```
cat /etc/*release | grep "^ID="
```

And I got it with Ubuntu and Centos as well.

Comment: Almost perfect. An AWS Suse instance was giving me a hard time but an across the board: `less /etc/os-release | grep "^ID="` does the trick on all three. Thanks. Definitely a +1.

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh Right, all three of those are using systemd, See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will share the code of a script I'm doing which support more than 12 different linux systems and detects if the system is arm based. At the beginning there is an array on which you must put the linux you support. It has two phases. First one is to search the words in the array against the output of the uname command. And the second one is to check the special existing in /etc which depends of the distro.

```
#!/bin/bash

is_arm=0

#Distros vars
known_compatible_distros=(
                        "Wifislax"
                        "Kali"
                        "Parrot"
                        "Backbox"
                        "Blackarch"
                        "Cyborg"
                        "Ubuntu"
                        "Debian"
                        "SuSE"
                        "CentOS"
                        "Gentoo"
                        "Fedora"
                        "Red Hat"
                        "Arch"
                        "OpenMandriva"
                    )

known_arm_compatible_distros=(
                        "Raspbian"
                        "Parrot arm"
                        "Kali arm"
                    )

#First phase of Linux distro detection based on uname output
function detect_distro_phase1() {

    for i in "${known_compatible_distros[@]}"; do
        uname -a | grep "${i}" -i > /dev/null
        if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
            distro="${i^}"
            break
        fi
    done
}

#Second phase of Linux distro detection based on architecture and version file
function detect_distro_phase2() {

    if [ "${distro}" = "Unknown Linux" ]; then
        if [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"centos-release" ]; then
            distro="CentOS"
        elif [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"fedora-release" ]; then
            distro="Fedora"
        elif [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"gentoo-release" ]; then
            distro="Gentoo"
        elif [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"openmandriva-release" ]; then
            distro="OpenMandriva"
        elif [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"redhat-release" ]; then
            distro="Red Hat"
        elif [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"SuSE-release" ]; then
            distro="SuSE"
        elif [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"debian_version" ]; then
            distro="Debian"
            if [ -f ${osversionfile_dir}"os-release" ]; then
                extra_os_info=$(cat < ${osversionfile_dir}"os-release" | grep "PRETTY_NAME")
                if [[ "${extra_os_info}" =~ Raspbian ]]; then
                    distro="Raspbian"
                    is_arm=1
                elif [[ "${extra_os_info}" =~ Parrot ]]; then
                    distro="Parrot arm"
                    is_arm=1
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi

    detect_arm_architecture
}

#Detect if arm architecture is present on system
function detect_arm_architecture() {

    distro_already_known=0
    uname -m | grep -i "arm" > /dev/null

    if [[ "$?" = "0" ]] && [[ "${distro}" != "Unknown Linux" ]]; then

        for item in "${known_arm_compatible_distros[@]}"; do
            if [ "${distro}" = "${item}" ]; then
                distro_already_known=1
            fi
        done

        if [ ${distro_already_known} -eq 0 ]; then
            distro="${distro} arm"
            is_arm=1
        fi
    fi
}

detect_distro_phase1
detect_distro_phase2

echo "${distro}"
echo "${is_arm}"
```

Of course it can be improved... maybe changing the "elif" chain to a case or that kind of things... but this is fully working. I hope it helps to you.

Comment: Hey Oscar, thanks a lot, nice work. I quickly tested it on a few machines. 2 RHEL servers, one in AWS - and it does not return anything for OS, and 0 for Arm. AWS Suse does not echo anything. Ubuntu works like a charm. Any idea where I may be going wrong?

Comment: I never used Suse AWS sorry. It seems the word "suse" is not appearing in the output of `uname -a` command on Suse AWS and it seems too that there is not `SuSE-release` file in /etc. To modify this to detect that you must check what is the name of the file existing in /etc and add an "elif" with that name in the phase 2 detection. For Red Hat I guess is working because Red Hat servers always have the `redhat-release` file in /etc, right?

Comment: Redhat does have `/etc/redhat-release` but uname -all does not return the distro name / family. Nor does Suse. See below:
RHEL - `Linux <servername> <xx.xx.xx>.20.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 24 12:23:56 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Suse - `Linux ip-<xx.xx.xx.xx>.us-west-2.compute.internal 4.4.21-69-default #1 SMP Tue Oct 25 10:58:20 UTC 2016 (9464f67) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Ubuntu - `Linux ip-<xx.xx.xx.xx> 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: No problem that's because the phase 2 exists. If not name in uname output it looks for the existence of the file in etc so red hat must be working! do you have a file called /etc/redhat-release ? if yes, it must be detected as red-hat

Answer (score 1):

So, I got hung up on this and after a day of digging found this:
http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html

Then another day's work/merge and testing resulted in the following script that actually's been tested to run on

- Solaris
- RedHat
- Ubuntu
- SuSe

If any of you have a way to check any other distros, I'd be much obliged.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Detects which OS and if it is Linux then it will detect which Linux
# Distribution.
# from http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html
#


OS=`uname -s`
REV=`uname -r`
MACH=`uname -m`

GetVersionFromFile()
{
    VERSION=`cat $1 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*VERSION.*=\ // `
}

if [ "${OS}" = "Darwin" ]; then
    OIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'
    set `sw_vers` > /dev/null
    DIST=`echo $1 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed 's/ProductName:[ ]*//'`
    VERSION=`echo $2 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed 's/ProductVersion:[ ]*//'`
    BUILD=`echo $3 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed 's/BuildVersion:[ ]*//'`
    OSSTR="${OS} ${DIST} ${REV}(SORRY_NO_PSEUDONAME ${BUILD} ${MACH})"
    IFS="$OIFS"

elif [ "${OS}" = "SunOS" ] ; then
    OS=Solaris
    ARCH=`uname -p` 
    OSSTR="${OS} ${REV}(${ARCH} `uname -v`)"

elif [ "${OS}" = "AIX" ] ; then
    OSSTR="${OS} `oslevel` (`oslevel -r`)"
elif [ "${OS}" = "Linux" ] ; then
    KERNEL=`uname -r`
    if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ] ; then
        DIST='RedHat'
        PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
        REV=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
    elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ] ; then
        DIST=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' '| sed s/VERSION.*//`
        REV=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*=\ //`
    elif [ -f /etc/mandrake-release ] ; then
        DIST='Mandrake'
        PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
        REV=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ] ; then
        DIST="Debian `cat /etc/debian_version`"
        REV=""
    elif [ -f /etc/UnitedLinux-release ] ; then
        DIST="${DIST}[`cat /etc/UnitedLinux-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/VERSION.*//`]"
    fi

    OSSTR="${OS} ${DIST} ${REV}(${PSUEDONAME} ${KERNEL} ${MACH})"

fi

echo ${OSSTR}
```